# Selfbot can't read activities of user

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to print a users current [activity(s)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.activities). If I am listening to spotify, it should return (Spotify). I tested this by listening to spotify and run the command on myself, however it prints an empty tuple. If I use this command on a friend and they have spotify or any games running, it will return all there current their activities.

> Main Script (/bot/Main.py)

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
extensions = ['cogs.bot']

selfbot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',self_bot=True)
loop.create_task(selfbot.start(personalToken, bot=False))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    selfbot.load_extension(extensions[1])
    
loop.run_forever()
```

> Cog (/bot/cogs/bot.py)

```
class bot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def activities(self, ctx, user=None):
        if user == None:
            user = ctx.author
            
        else:
            user = ctx.message.mentions[0]
    
        for activity in user.activities:
            print('activity:', activity)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(bot(bot))
```

How can I make it print out my activities and why won't it print out with the current code?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it multiple times with different ways and had the same issue, after some searching, I figured out it was an issue with discord you can't see your **own status** since bots can't get their own status.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if there is a way to find out what the users activities are without using discord.py then.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but as I said what I am sure about is that you can't get yours with discord.py, if the answer was helpful please mark it as correct

Comment: I am not going to mark it correct, because it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can see your own activities (and your own status and custom status). There're multiple ways to do this, but I recommend using [discum](https://github.com/Merubokkusu/Discord-S.C.U.M), an API wrapper for selfbots/userbots. Note that discum is only maintained for selfbots/userbots and will not work on actual BOT accounts.

Here's an example (using discum):

```py
import discum
bot = discum.Client(token='your token here')

@bot.gateway.command
def helloworldsomething(resp):
    if resp.event.session_replaced:
        print(f"activities: {bot.gateway.session.userSettings['activities']}")

bot.gateway.run()
```

Also, while the gateway is running, you can get the client's current status and custom status using:
`bot.gateway.session.userSettings['status']`
and
`bot.gateway.session.userSettings['custom_status']`